# Did Olympe (Madame Maxime) love Hagrid?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid, love

At moments it seems as though the two are truly in love but at others it seems like she's using him. She gets all mad at Hagrid for saying the truth, and lies to him. Maybe she just wanted to get away from Hagrid. The reason she wanted to make up with him was to find out about the 3rd task early (at least, to my understanding,) and after Hagrid comes back in *Order of the Phoenix*, there was no Olympe Maxime.

Comment: Olympe agreed to go with Hagrid to the Giant-quest. Perhaps it was love? Olympe also appeared comforting Hagrid in Dumbledore funeral.

Comment: @Roberto I have plenty of friends who I'd comfort at a funeral.  Also friends I work with and go on business trips with.  I'm not in love with them though.

Comment: @Graham Do you also go to weddings with your friends as a plus one?

Comment: @Roberto It's not clear that she was.  Fleur was Maxime's star pupil, so it's far more likely she'd be invited by Fleur in her own right, due to them being friends (or mentor/mentee).  OOU of course, Rowling had a limited number of named people connected to Fleur who she could write into a wedding scene. :)

Comment: @Graham Good point!

Comment: @Roberto There's nothing wrong with going to a wedding with a friend as a plus one. Although certainly some people may assume you're in a relationship (because "that's just what you're supposed to do").

Comment: @NotThatGuy It's pretty unusual to go with friends as a plus one, as far as I know.

Answer (score 10):

### She thought he was "kind of cute", but not "sophisticated" enough.

Shortly after the release of Book Seven, J.K. Rowling did a book reading event at Carnegie Hall. One of the questions she was asked there was about if Hagrid ever gets married.

There's no surviving recording of the event, but here are three different accounts from people present:

> Q: Did Hagrid ever get married and have children?
>
> [Aww from crowd] JKR: Oh, did Hagrid ever get married and have children? No. [awwws again] I may change that immediately due to the look on your face. Yes! He had 22! – No, no, Hagrid never did marry and have children. I’m sorry. I’m really sorry. Oh I feel terrible now. I’ll write another book! [Ovation] Realistically, Hagrid’s pool of potential girlfriends is extremely limited. Because with the giants killing each other off, the number of giantesses around is infinitesimal and he met one of the only, and I’m afraid, **she thought he was kind of cute, but she was a little more, how should I put it, sophisticated than Hagrid.** So no, bless him. [Awws] I kept him alive, come on! [Applause.]
> <sub>[The Leaky Cauldron](https://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more/) (said to be accurate in meaning but not phrasing)</sub>

> Did Hagrid ever get married….No.
>
> Crowd does sad: “Awwwwww….”
>
> No, Hagrid never did get married, actually.  I’m sorry.
>
> Realistically, Hagrid’s pool of potential girlfriends is extremely limited. With Giants killing each other constantly the number of Giantesses around is infinitesimal. And he met one of the only ones.  And I’m afraid **she though he was kind of cute, but she was a little more – how can I put it? – sophisticated than Hagrid.** So no, bless him, no.
> <sub>[iamstarmom livejournal](https://iamstarmom.livejournal.com/12237.html) (based on [a recording](https://capella-black.livejournal.com/7025.html?thread=52337#t52337))</sub>

> Question: Did Hagrid ever marry and have children?
>
> Answer: No. His pool of potential mates was small. **Madame Maxime thought he was cute, but in the end she was more sophisticated than he was, and they didn't really connect.** (The lady who asked this question - at sixty-three, she was the oldest person to ask a question - was unhappy with this answer, and Rowling joked, "Hey, at least he survived!")
> <sub>[eldritchhobbit livejournal](https://eldritchhobbit.livejournal.com/175955.html) (based on "notes")</sub>